# How to filter out URL parameters in Google Analytics when the parameter is dynamically named?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

We use Spredfast for our social management platform, and it appends a dynamic URL parameter on the end of every link it points to our website. I want a GA filter that removes anything that matches this dynamic parameter.

These are all valid ways the URL parameter comes into the website:

```
www.website.com/?sf12345=1
www.website.com/?sf54321=1
www.website.com/?sf12345678=1
```

We have determined that the number of digits after the "sf" is anywhere from 4-8 digits long and the parameter is always set to =1

I have found solutions for matching and removing a specific URL paramter, however since this parameter changes with every link published in Spredfast, those methods are not working for me.

Could anyone suggest how to create a GA Filter on our view that will remove only the parameter that matches this syntax?

Appreciations in advance!
Thanks,
pat

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the regex, but haven't tested this filter. It should work though:

1. Create a new filter > search and replace
2. select 'Request URI' //the filter help says includes the hostname. this is what I'm not sure about including.
3. search string:  `example\.com/\?sf(.*)=1$`
4. replace string: `example\.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a new filter /
Custom filter /
Exclude
Request URI:

```
^/?sf(.*)
```